# Relationship between tables to prevent insertion of records where foreign key doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, database-design, relational-database

Hi I've set up two very basic tables. One table will act as a look up, with an identity field as a primary key. The other table uses the look up ID as a foreign key.

I have created a relationship constraint so now I cannot delete from the look up if the foreign key is used in the "main" table.

However my issue is i can add a  record with a foreign key that doesn't exist.

To my way of thinking this shouldn't be allowed, can anyone tell me what setting I need to use to enforce this and whether this is typical database design or not?

Thanks Dave

Comment: I must have created the relationship incorrectly. I recreated through database diagrams and its fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You way of thinking is correct.  Good database design provides some way of enforcing what is called "Referential Integrity".  This is simply a buzzword for the concept you have derived on your own.  Namely that a foreign key should be rejected if it refers to a non existent row.  For a general discussion of referential integrity, see the following Wikipedia article.  It's short.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity

Some pprogrammers would like to enforce referential integrity inside their programs.  In general, it's a much better plan to define a referential integrity constraint inside the database, and let the DBMS do the enforcement.  It's easier, it's faster, and it's more effective.

The SQL Data Definition Language (DDL) provides a way to declare a foreign key constraint when you create a table.  The syntax differs a little between different dialects of SQL, but it's basically the same idea in all of them.  Here's a capsule summary.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

The documentation for SQL Server should have a description of the referential integrity constraint under the CREATE TABLE command.